# Setting draggable options in javascript

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

Attempting to get an answer to this question.  How can I turn off the draggable option in javascript?  The api documentation is saying

.draggable({disable: true});

or

.draggable("option", "disable", true);

Neither does it for me.  Here are the libraries I have.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
```

I javascript I attempt to turn off the draggable option in code like this.

```
 editable.parent().draggable({disable: true});
 editable.parent().draggable("option", "disable", true);
```

editable.parent() does find the right element, but the draggable option isn't turned off.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 editable.parent().draggable({disabled: true});
```

Or:

```
editable.parent().draggable("option", "disabled", true);
```

Either should work. You forgot the 'd' on the end of `disabled`

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure the selector is ok

2)

```
.draggable("disable")
```